# Confusing Scala type mismatch error with 'uncheckedVariance' in signature

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, type-mismatch

First the error:

```
/Users/rob/Workspace/Boiled.scala:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : DataSetup{type Mem <: Product with Serializable{val ids: List[Int]; def copy(ids: List[Int]): this.Mem; def copy$default$1: List[Int]}; object Mem; type Memory = this.Mem}
 required: DataSetup{type Mem <: Product with Serializable{val ids: List[Int]; def copy(ids: List[Int]): this.Mem; def copy$default$1: List[Int] @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance}; object Mem; type Memory = this.Mem}
 val dataSetup = new DataSetup {
     ^
```

Lovely isn't it?  It points to a line where I try to create an instance of the `DataSetup` trait.  It is of course a boiled-down version of the real code.

```
trait DataSetup {
  type Memory <: AnyRef with Serializable 
  def run(): Memory
}

object Use {

  val dataSetup = new DataSetup {     // <---- error reported here
    case class Mem(ids: List[Int])
    type Memory = Mem
    def run(): Memory = {
      val ids = List(1,2,3)
      Mem(ids)
    }
  }

}
```

I really have no idea what it's complaining about.  Anyone?

Comment: For the record, it works if you just name your case class Memory. A subclass can "implement" an abstract type with a class or trait.

Comment: Another working variant: change `val dataSetup = new` to `object dataSetup extends`

Comment: Still another: `val dataSetup: DataSetup = ...`. Interestingly, in 2.9 the error message is worded a bit different: `found   : Use.dataSetup.type (with underlying type ... `

Comment: I've lodged this bug: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8071 and will take a look at it

Comment: This is fixed for Scala 2.11: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3267. In any case, I do recommend using type annotations (e.g `val dataSetup: DataSetup = new ...`) for anonymous classes, especially if they end up in public API.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the error messages have improved in the latest 2.11 milestone.

```
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : DataSetup{type Mem(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>) <: Product with Serializable{val ids: List[Int]; def copy(ids: List[Int]): this.Mem(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>); def copy$default$1: List[Int]}; type Memory = this.Mem(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)}
 required: DataSetup{type Mem(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>) <: Product with Serializable{val ids: List[Int]; def copy(ids: List[Int]): this.Mem(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>); def copy$default$1: List[Int] @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance}; object Mem; type Memory = this.Mem(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)(in <refinement of DataSetup>)}
         val dataSetup = new DataSetup {     // <---- error reported here
             ^
```

Anyway, it looks like the annotation (added synthetically to a default arg method of `copy`) is lost in the inferred type.

```
val dataSetup: DataSetup = new DataSetup {     // <---- no error here
```

Obviously, the type doesn't conform without the annotation.  It's worth asking why:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8071

with another classic paulpism:

> I lost count at some point but I didn't notice that many refinements
>   of AnyRef.

Comment: I wasn't supposed to actually fix it to earn a green check, right?  Some of us are only paid in green checks.